# Wordpress - How to Display Posts Grouped by Category?

Tags: wordpress, categories

I want to display post titles grouped by category as such in WordPress:

Category: Apples
 - Post Title One
 - Post Title Two
 - Post Title ....

Category: Oranges
 - Post Title One
 - Post Title Two
 - Post Title ....

I need the code to accomplish this, not a plugin or category widget.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display Posts from a category in Wordpress?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735959/display-posts-from-a-category-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to creating a "Archive by Category Page" and can be done with the following code:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <div class="entry">
            <?php the_content('<p class="serif">Read the rest of this page &raquo;</p>'); ?>

            <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p><strong>Pages:</strong> ', 'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    <!-- Category Archive Start -->
    <ul class="catArchive">
    <?php
    $catQuery = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->terms AS wterms INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS wtaxonomy ON ( wterms.term_id = wtaxonomy.term_id ) WHERE wtaxonomy.taxonomy = 'category' AND wtaxonomy.parent = 0 AND wtaxonomy.count > 0");

    $catCounter = 0;

    foreach ($catQuery as $category) {

        $catCounter++;

        $catStyle = '';
        if (is_int($catCounter / 2)) $catStyle = ' class="catAlt"';

        $catLink = get_category_link($category->term_id);

        echo '<li'.$catStyle.'><h3><a href="'.$catLink.'" title="'.$category->name.'">'.$category->name.'</a></h3>';
            echo '<ul>';

            query_posts('cat='.$category->term_id.'&showposts=5');?>

            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

                <li><a href="<?php echo $catLink; ?>" title="<?php echo $category->name; ?>">More <strong><?php echo $category->name; ?></strong></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <!-- Category Archive End -->
```

Note that the code above will only display categories that have posts associated with them, otherwise they will be skipped.

Also, it'll only show the last 5 posts under each category. You can change that by altering the number after the showposts variable. For example, you could change:

```
query_posts('cat='.$category->term_id.'&showposts=5');
```

to one where you displayed 10 posts:

```
query_posts('cat='.$category->term_id.'&showposts=10');
```

Substitute the line above into the loop at the very beginning and you should have a functioning "Archive by Category" page.